# How to make UNIX-Python-executable work in VS Code via "select interpreter" on a Windows machine?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pythoninterpreter

I was forced to use [WSL on Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) to install the Python library [Cartopy](https://pypi.org/project/Cartopy/) on my Windows machine correctly. It is way easier in a Linux-distribution, so I chose Ubuntu 20.04 WSL2.

As a consequence, I created a virtual Python environment via WSL in my project folder via `python -m venv linux-venv`.
The problem is now that all binaries/executables were compiled for the WSL-distribution and are thus not selectable from [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) started from within Windows 10.

Consequently, I installed VS Code on WSL and started it from there.
My hope was that I can then [manually select the right interpreter path](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter) `linux-venv/bin/python` from my project's root directory.
Unfortunately, it does not work either, even though I'm doing this from VS Code running on WSL:

[image: select interpreter path]

Clicking on my desired interpreter `linux-venv/bin/python`, the following error message is displayed:

[image: error message]

If I try to "browse to my desired executable" instead, they are not displayed since solely ".exe" - file extensions are allowed:

[image: browse1]

Next, I can solely browse ".exe" - files, wherefore I cannot select the UNIX-compiled executables.

[image: browse2]

---

**Conclusion:**

*It does not seem possible at the moment to select a UNIX-compiled interpreter in VS Code properly on a Windows 10 - machine, not even using WSL.*

Since the aforementioned Python library [Cartopy](https://pypi.org/project/Cartopy/) solely works well on UNIX-systems, I need to install my virtual environment from WSL.

In order to continue with my project, **I would need to be able to select the UNIX-compiled interpreter**, but I cannot.

Comment: Have you tried WSL extension : https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/09/03/wsl2

Comment: I have this extension installed. Yet, it does not help solve my above-mentioned problem. In the associated blog posts of your WSL2-link, the "selected interpreter" is always preselected and "just works". It seems to me as if they just use the global Python environment instead a local virtual environment. At least I don't see anything like how it is activated within VS Code via e.g. "select interpreter".

Comment: Do you use the installed extension ? If yes, you should be able to select any interpreter in WSL, including virtual environments.

Comment: What version of python are you using? Is this [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial) useful?

Comment: The Python version is 3.9x.
The docs are useful, but I just realized that if I select an existing workspace, the remote-connection to WSL vanishes (button in the bottom-left).
Probably this happens, when the workspace had been created from within Windows. Could this be?

Comment: Via trial and error I finally found out what the problems were. Thanks though for hinting me again to the official docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Analysis:**

I figured out what the actual problems were in order to make it work according to the kindly shared [WSL-docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial) by @Philippe and @JialeDu:

1. The [VS-Code Workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces) had been created from within Windows 10.
2. The [Python virtual environment (venv)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) was installed via a [WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/know-how/wsl2-explained/) - CLI, yet into a project folder on the C-Drive on Windows 10.

Consequently, starting VS-Code from within WSL or clicking on the "remote button" provided by the [WSL-extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial) was fine, but when I opened the project it was still located on the Windows-C-drive. This silently broke the remote connection to WSL and left me working in VS-Code in Windows just like normally.

Obviously, this made it impossible to search for UNIX-executables and even select them, since I was effectively working on Windows, not on Linux (WSL).

**Solution:**

1. Migrate the entire project folder from the C-Drive `C:\Users\username\Projects\project_name` to the actual Ubuntu-WSL-System in `/home/username/projects/project_name`.
2. Create the virtual environment anew in the project folder via `python3 -m venv linux-venv`.
3. Install all [requirements](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/) again in that environment just created.
4. Install the [VS-Code Python Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) in the current WSL-version of VS-Code
5. Open a Python-file and select the interpreter of the venv just configured

This time, **it worked since I was effectively working on a true Linux environment/distribution** with all packages and binaries installed within WSL.

*Not only did I have to migrate the entire project on the WSL-distribution's directory tree, but I also had to reinstall the requirements and binaries of the virtual environments from there.*

Comment: I dont think you have to migrate the entire project folder from the C-Drive to WSL, as you can access `/mnt/c/Users/username/Projects/project_name` from WSL

Comment: In VS Code, the remote connection to WSL always vanished if I chose to open the folder on the C-Drive. Even after removing the workspace file etc.